Can an adult who was incarcerated as a minor sue for damages?
A child that had never committed a criminal offence was incarcerated multiple times, subjected to sexual assault via cavity searches, humiliation, and isolation.
Now wants to sue the state as an adult.
How can that be accomplished in the U.S.A?

By having a consultation with a lawyer. The lawyer will advise you on further steps to take.

Did they complete their sentence, or were they exonerated due to an appeal?

This cannot be accomplished in the United States given only the facts presented in the question.
Incarcerating someone who didn't commit a crime does not create civil or criminal liability unless that person was arrested without probable cause, or was convicted of a crime due to a violation of a constitutional right.
Cavity searches, humiliation, and isolation do not violate the constitutional rights of someone who is arrested with probable cause, or who is convicted of a crime in a case where there is not violation of a constitutional right by the prosecution, even if the person incarcerated was actually innocent.
The question does not describe any facts that violate a clearly establish an intentional violation of a constitutional right of the child by a law enforcement official, which is the relevant legal standard in this situation. The primary statute authorizing lawsuits for violation of one's rights in these circumstances is 42 U.S.C. § 1983.
It is possible that other facts could be present that would give rise to a right to sue, but the facts found in the question are not sufficient to prove a case where there is a ground to sue.
To be clear, as the person writing this answer, I am not saying that this legal standard is a good or just one. But this is the relevant legal standard under existing law, which makes it hard to sue law enforcement and other people involved in the criminal justice system.
In terms of time limit for someone to sue for a § 1983 violation that occurred when the person was a minor (assuming for the sake of argument that facts not mentioned in the question provide a basis for a § 1983 lawsuit), there isn't one simple answer.
In this situation, the statute of limitations is based upon the statute of limitations for lawsuits similar to § 1983 lawsuits in the state where the § 1983 violation occurred. See, e.g., here. So, there is one statute of limitations in New York State, another in California, and a third in Utah. There isn't one uniform national rule in the United States regarding the deadline for filing lawsuits in these situations. Some states require you to sue when you are a minor. Other states allow you to sue for anything that happened while you were a minor until you are twenty-one years old. And, other states have different, more complicated, rules about when, if ever, an adult can sue for violations of their constitutional rights that took place the person suing was a minor.

One might add that the justice system does not even try to deal with actually being guilty or innocent, it deals with being found guilty or not guilty, or sufficiently probably guilty.

@o.m. While there is a currently a split of authority on the issue, many federal court authorities have recognized a right to collaterally attack convictions based upon actual innocence, although this is the ground most often raised which least often prevails in such challenges. But a litigated court finding of guilt or probable cause will usually bind someone suing under § 1983 under an issue preclusion/collateral estoppel legal theory.

My point was in regard to the first line of the question, "... had never committed ..." Even a defense based on actual innocence would rely on evidence pointing one way or the other, not on the metaphysical truth or whatever one wants to call it.
